# MVVM - ComboBox binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i have a Datagrid with binding to an observableCollection.
The ArticleViewmodel is a Wrapper of Artcle-Class.
Now i want to Show a Combobox in the same View with the manufacterer of the Article.
Should i create a separate Viewmodel with manufacteres or ho could this managed ?

bye jogi

Comment: No, just create an `ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>` and bind your combobox to it

Comment: ok, but i get my List of Article by a articlerepository in the viewmodel. Were should i get my manufacterer. They are stored in a database. Should i make then a separate manufacturerrepository, or a helperrepository for unique functions ?

Comment: can you share your code? it will be easier to get the actual problem and propose a solution